# need mongofiles.exe file for windows 32 bit system

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Can anyone please help me in finding the mongofiles.exe for windows 32bit because it is missing from my bin folder. for 64 bit it is there but its showing compatibilty issues. Please help

Comment: This is basically off-topic as it really has nothing to do with programming as such. But the basic concept here is that it seems your target system has been selected for a server install only where the other tools have not been installed. Follow the instructions at [Windows Installation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), or otherwise install tools on a different host or other client.

Comment: i want to push mp3 file into mongodb database thts why i need to have mongofiles.exe command which is showing compatibility issue.

Comment: @manishankar, the default installation doesn't install those but if you were to select "Custom" you could then enable "Miscellaneous Tools" and that would install mongofiles and a few other binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the latest builds for 2.4 and 2.6 here:

http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-v2.6-latest.zip
http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-v2.4-latest.zip

Each of those zip files contains all of the MongoDB executables including mongofiles.exe.  For a full list of 32-bit builds:

http://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386

Comment: Thanx a lot adam, but i have already installed mongodb v2.6 in my windows 32 bit system. I only need the mongofiles.exe which is missing from my bin folder.

Comment: right, and if you download the files I linked and extract them you will find mongofiles.exe there